# Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error The tag 'VideoResultControl' does not exist in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to implement Microsoft emotion api in C# using code available on github. I followed all the steps given in https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Emotion-api/documentation/GetStarted. 
I have 3 errors, some of them is:

Error : The tag 'VideoResultControl' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:SampleUserControlLibrary;assembly=SampleUserControlLibrary'. Line 28 Position 10.

Error:  The tag 'SampleScenarios' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:SampleUserControlLibrary;assembly=SampleUserControlLibrary'. Line 12 Position 10.

In Solution Explorer, "SampleUserControlLibrary (Load fail)" appears: that means no user controls libraries are loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem

The problem here is your SampleUserControlLibrary is not loaded. Because -

> Cognitive-Common-Windows is a git submodule

So, todos are -

```
git submodule init

git submodule update
```

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Emotion-Windows/issues/4)