# Microsoft Emotion API implementation Error

Tags: c#, nuget-package, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to implement Microsoft emotion api in C# using code available on github. I followed all the steps given in [Microsoft Cognitive Service](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Emotion-api/documentation/GetStarted). I have 3 errors

```
Error : The tag 'VideoResultControl' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:SampleUserControlLibrary;assembly=SampleUserControlLibrary'

Error: The tag 'SampleScenarios' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:SampleUserControlLibrary;assembly=SampleUserControlLibrary'.

Error NuGet Package restore failed for project EmotionAPI-WPF-Samples: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters
```

I found a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258634/severitycodedescriptionprojectfilelinesuppression-state-error-the-tag-vid) (except for the change in the third question) but no answers.

I tried deleting the `.suo` file to fix the last error, but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of research, I resolved the solution.
For the first two errors, i found out that

> Cognitive-Common-Windows is a git submodule

So, todos are -

```
git submodule init

git submodule update
```

For the third Problem, `I temporarily moved the project to an upper directory tree so that the path name is not too long` 
More info can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Emotion-Windows/issues/4) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Emotion-Windows/issues/7)